# Cannot Find Local Module When Using Import (Error: Cannot find module '../Definitions/Types')

Tags: typescript

Until just recently, when running my program to test that it all works, I get an error when I try to import my types.d.ts, but only when I import it in two files, all other files are completely fine.
(File Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPVBc.jpg)

index.ts import:

```
import { CommandJSONExport, CommandInterface } from "./Definitions/types";
```

handlers.ts import:

```
import { CommandInterface, CommandJSONExport, ConstructorOptions } from "../Definitions/types";
```

The Error Message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../Definitions/types'
Require stack:
- F:\Coding\Command Handler\Handlers\handlers.ts
- F:\Coding\Command Handler\index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (C:\Users\sebas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:679:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Coding\Command Handler\Handlers\handlers.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\sebas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1371:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\sebas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1374:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'F:\\Coding\\Command Handler\\Handlers\\handlers.ts',
    'F:\\Coding\\Command Handler\\index.ts'
  ]
}
```

(Note: The folder I am working in ATM is the 'Command Handler' folder)
UPDATE: Getting rid of the types.d.ts import in my handlers.ts file fixes the error, but it still causes problems for me in other ways so I still need it to be imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem in the code of my handlers.ts file. Turns out that if you try to run an imported class like -in my case- `CommandInterface;` it give you that error. Weird, but at least I found my fix